# How to fix Error 1064 while creating tables with foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

MySql workbench tells me I have an error in my SQL syntax that corresponds to my MariaDB server version and I don't know why.

I've already looked at other questions but none of them seem to help so I'm asking my own question now... I really don't know what's wrong with my code and I don't know what the problem with my syntax is. I've tried to set some comas or rename the columns etc and I changed the SQL Version in the Model to the sql version I'm using with xampp. But still, after changing the version I'm getting that error...

The sql to create the tables is (I've took the comments out):

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `testDB` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `testDB` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testDB`.`person` (
  `personID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `lastname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`personID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testDB`.`comment` (
  `commentID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comment` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `person_personID` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`commentID`),
  INDEX `fk_comment_person_idx` (`person_personID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_comment_person`
    FOREIGN KEY (`person_personID`)
    REFERENCES `testDB`.`person` (`personID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
  CONSTRAINT `fk_comment_person`
    FOREIGN KEY (`person_personID`)
    REFERE' at line 9
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `testDB`.`comment`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testDB`.`comment` (
          `commentID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `comment` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `person_personID` INT NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`commentID`),
          INDEX `fk_comment_person_idx` (`person_personID` ASC) VISIBLE,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_comment_person`
            FOREIGN KEY (`person_personID`)
            REFERENCES `testDB`.`person` (`personID`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 6 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

Comment: Note: If nothing is wrong with the code quoted after `right syntax to use near`, the problem often lies just before that code, which is `VISIBLE` in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the word VISIBLE in your statement:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `testDB` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `testDB` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testDB`.`person` (
  `personID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `lastname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`personID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testDB`.`comment` (
  `commentID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comment` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `person_personID` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`commentID`),
  INDEX `fk_comment_person_idx` (`person_personID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_comment_person`
    FOREIGN KEY (`person_personID`)
    REFERENCES `testDB`.`person` (`personID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Because in MariaDB is not yet implemented the INVISIBLE option. This option is implemented in ORACLE

Comment: @Lars - Note that even for oracles MySQL `VISIBLE` is default. So there is no need to set it explicitly.